# Getting a lazy list of the first n items of a lazy list

Tags: clojure, sequences

In Clojure, I have a list

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

and I want to pull out of it a new infinite list of tuples

```
[ [a,b,c], [b,c,d], [c,d,a], [d,a,b], [a,b,c] ... ]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in a purely functional way with the built-in seq functions.

Is this straightforward and I haven't cracked it yet? Or is it actually some kind of hard problem? (In other languages I'd write my own circular iterators and keep track of a lot of state.)

Update : Also, why is someone voting this down?

Comment: I think the downvote is because you didn't show what you've done so far.

Comment: `(take 5 (partition 3 1 (cycle '(a b c d))))`

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. I didn't know about the three argument version of Partition.

Comment: @m0skit0 I was trying lots of different combinations of things. And then throwing them away when they didn't work. I assumed that if someone knew the right way to do it, they wouldn't necessarily want or need to see all my failed attempts.

Comment: @Kyle That works for me. If you make it an answer I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: If I were downvoting this, it would be because your title doesn't match your problem description at all: the way to get the first N items from a lazy sequence is just `take`! Reading your example input+output I was quite confused trying to reconcile it with your explanation.

Comment: @amalloy Do you have a better suggestion? I know it's clunkily phrased but it does describe what I was trying to get.

Comment: @amalloy would something like "a moving window through a lazy list" explain things better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a combination of [cycle](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cycle) and [partition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition)

```
(take 5 (partition 3 1 (cycle '(a b c d))))
;; => ((a b c) (b c d) (c d a) (d a b) (a b c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using partition:

```
(defn next-rotation [coll]
  (take (count coll) (drop 1 (cycle coll))))

(defn tuples [n coll]
  (lazy-seq (cons (take n coll) (tuples n (next-rotation coll)))))

;; (take 5 (tuples 3 '(a b c d))) ;; =>
;; ((a b c) (b c d) (c d a) (d a b) (a b c))
```